# Shifting Margins in Relative Positioned Div

Tags: html, css, position

I have a fixed header that I've set up with a higher z-index than the body content so the content slips underneath it. In order to position the `content div` right below the fixed header, I set its `position:relative` and gave it a `top value`

This seemed to work fine, until I started to add items to the `content div`. First I added an `h1` and as I attempted to give it a little `margin-top` the entire page (header and all) shifted down the value I specified for my margin-top.

I've run into this before (collapsing divs yes?) and I've usually been able to fix it with a set width or a float or a display block, but none of these seem to be doing the trick.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header
{
    background-color: white;
    color: #724444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(140, 140, 140, .2);
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#header-fixedWidth
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li
{
    margin: 0 10px;
}

#main-content
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 89px;
}

#main-content-fixedWidth
{
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}



.headers
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#image-deck
{
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

/*Media Queries*/

@media (max-width: 1000px)
{
    header
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #header-fixedWidth
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pic Monkey Recreation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="header-fixedWidth"
                <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="randomLogo" id="randomLogo" />
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/edit.png" alt="">
                            <br>
                            <p>Edit</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/touchUps.png" alt="">
                            <br>
                            <p>Touch Up</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/design.png" alt="">
                            <br>
                            <p>Design</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="Images/iconMenu/collage.png" alt="">
                            <br>
                            <p>Collage</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div id="user-help">
                    <img src="Images/signIn.png" alt="signIn" id="signIn" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="main-content">
            <div id="main-content-fixedWidth">
                <div id="test">
                    <p class="headers">Here is a header for you to look at</p>
                </div>
                <div id="image-deck"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a counter minus margin to offset the amount you have moved it. So if your box has a top value 50px and your inner h1 have a margin-top value 100px you'd need to reset your box top value to -50px to counter.